# Copy items via Finder and Applescript: how to get "item exists - replace?" dialog in Finder?

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

In my app, I like to have the OSX Finder copy a file or folder.

(*Note: I have good reasons for using the Finder instead of using shell cmds, NSWorkspace or other means, so there's no need for suggestions in that direction.*)

I am currently relying on Applescript for asking the Finder to perform the copy operation. Here's a sample script for testing:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        copy file POSIX file "/etc/bashrc" to folder POSIX file "/private/tmp"
        -- alternative with same behavior:
        --duplicate POSIX file "/etc/bashrc" to POSIX file "/private/tmp"
    on error errmesg number errn
        display dialog "Error thrown: " & errmesg
    end try
end tell
```

Now the problem is this: **If the destination item already exists, the script throws an error and cancels the copy operation.**

However, **I would rather have the Finder display the "item exists" dialog** that it shows when doing such a copy operation in the Finder interactively, like this one:

[image: Finder "item already exists" warning]

Now, here's the thing:
**If I run this script from the 3rd party app Script Debugger, then this dialog appears!**

So, obviously there is a way to get the Finder to display the dialog instead of throwing an exception. But how? Who knows the secret to this?

Comment: You could test whether the destination file exists first and handle this case yourself ?

Comment: Paul - Of course I could, but that's not relevant to this question or the situation I need to solve.

Comment: Sorry - I thought it might be a pragmatic solution if there is no way to get the required behaviour from the Finder.

Comment: Yes, it is a pragmatic solution, and one that's pretty obvious. In fact, that's what I do right now. But I posted this question because I want to avoid this work-around, I thought that was obvious.

Comment: People on SO have a very wide range of experience and knowledge, from complete beginners to highly advanced, so one can never reliably make assumptions about what might be obvious or not obvious to any given contributor. So forgive me for stating what to you is obvious, but be aware that SO is for everybody, regardless of their level of skill, so a statement of the seemingly obvious might actually be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for my own needs I've found a solution: Instead of using an AppleScript, I need to use the AppleEvents API directly.

There, I can supply the values `kAEAlwaysInteract | kAECanSwitchLayer` to `AESend`'s SendMode parameter. This makes the dialogs appear in the Finder (and also bring the Finder to front in this case).

For someone relying on AppleScript, though, this is not a solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

**It seem there actually is no way to get Finder to show the dialog when using AppleScript** – at least when the script is run in its regular environment. In my testing, both *Finder*’s and *System Events*’ file `move` commands consistently error out when the target is already present – the only difference being, besides the semantics, that Finder offers a `replacing` switch to suppress this behavior with `true` meaning the target file will be overwritten without prompting, but no option to set this to `ask` (see [this MacScripter thread](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=28628) for a discussion of the exact same question) .

Without hard knowledge of its inner workings, I can only hazard the guess the fact [Script Debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com/sd4/) handles this differently is most likely due to it **not** running scripts in the normal environment. It’s hard to imagine how it would hook into the inner workings of a script to do its job as a debugger without creating its own script execution layer. Such an intermediary layer might explain why commands are forwarded differently to applications – in the case of Finder and `move`, to the low level Finder copy routines, which will show the dialog.

Which leaves you with re-implementing that functionality yourself, [as suggested by Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430506/copy-items-via-finder-and-applescript-how-to-get-item-exists-replace-dialo#comment13465425_10430506), or moving to [AppleScript-ObjectiveC](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/index.html) (not my area of expertise, I’m afraid).

Comment: I've also sent a question to Latenightsw about this. Maybe they can tell me what's going on. Still waiting on an anwser, though. A while ago I also posted a question where SD did something much smarter than the rest, and people suggested that SD did something undoc'd. Turned out that it did conform to the official APIs, in the end. So I trust that SD does in this case just as well play by the rules. I should also point out that I'm running the test in SD in the non-Debugging mode. We'll see...

Comment: BTW, I also looked at the AE Events - they appear to be the same between SD and Apple's editor. Maybe it's some environmental setting I cannot see right now, such as that SD was built against a newer SDK, enabling this feature automagically (I've seen such things before on OSX).

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: oh, I wouldn’t want to suggest SD does something undocumented – just that the fact it interposes itself between the script and the event system could result in some calls being translated differently (though that sounds unlikely if you get the same AEs). Anyway, I’d love to hear their answer if you get one – would be nice to have a way to get the behavior you are after.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the link to MacScripter. I added my question there as well, and StefanK (why don't we switch to German ;) confirms my findings with SD. Now, still waiting for LNS to respond... Unless they don't know why this happens, either :)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: StackEx is dead bent against people using anything but English (aber chatten können wir dann gern auf Deutsch, sollte es dazu kommen ;) – hope that does not bring down the lightning and thunder from on high). Anyway, as to SD, it’s also possible it is in fact Finder’s AppleScript dictionary that bypasses the full option range of the operation by always setting how to handle copy operation conflicts. Would explain how SD can send the exact same AE but get different results.

Comment: Good point, kopischke. I shall try to send a self-constructed AE, leaving out the option to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Mark Alldritt, SD developer, has responded and informed me that he's been investigating this before (i.e. the oddity was known to him), and he could not figure out why this is happening. The intesting part is, though, that he mentioned that SD is using its own OSA Component to isse the script commands. Maybe therein lies the secret. Writing my own OSA Component may not be easy to verify this suspicion, though :(

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Which means SD does indeed bypass AS’ normal ways to send its events. Basically confirms my suspicion…

Comment: well, no. If I understand Mark correctly, he's just using the official OSA APIs that other AppleScripts use as well. So, he's not working around anything, he's just using the proper ways, like any other AS.

Comment: I'm sure Mark knows very well how OSA and AS work, so if he says that he had investigated this, I trust him he'd be able to figure this out if he'd knowingly "work around" something there. It's more likely the Finder uses irregular ways to decide whether to show the dialog or return an AppleEvent error, and it makes the decision based on something that - accidentally - gives a false positive when SD is calling. I'd contact DTS about it if I wouldn't know that their Finder team is pretty uncapable to fix even the most obvious bugs (I have a few in the queue there...)

Comment: I think we might be talking a bit at cross purposes here, basically meaning the same thing (I’m not trying to lobby you for an accept, BTW – just following up out of interest). I’d still guess the issue is more one of low level translation to the Finder APIs, as *System Events* display the same behavior, but I won’t argue my point as my understanding of OSA and programming components for it is near to nil – I’m sure Mark is far more qualified than me to judge that (he and about 99.99999 % of all OS X devs alive :)). Would love to read his full take, though, if possible at all.

Answer (score -1):

This may be late but if you delete the file before you copy it thats the same as replacing:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists file ("NewFilePath") then
        delete file ("NewFilePath")
            -- NewFilePath Is where the file will end up or already is
    end if
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    try
        copy file POSIX file "FilePath" to folder POSIX file "FolderPath"
        -- FilePath is where it is now
        -- FolderPath is the path of the folder you want the file in
    on error errmesg number errn
        display dialog "Error thrown: " & errmesg
    end try
end tell
```

and since theres no choice between replace or stop finder should not bring up such a window

Comment: But I _want_ the "are you sure" dialog to appear when necessary, so that the user can choose whether to replace the existing item. And adding my own check and then showing my own dialog is not feasible for other reasons I can't explain in a few words.